# Mockito.doNothing not working for Handler

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm getting the following error when I'm running the unit test:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method removeCallbacks in
>   android.os.Handler not mocked. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
>
> at android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks(Handler.java)

Shouldn't the Mockito.doNothing() prevent the method removeCallbacks to be ran?

## Test class:

```
    @Mock
    private lateinit var handler: Handler

    private lateinit var myClass: MyClass

    init {
        initMocks(this)
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        myClass = MyClass()
        doNothing().`when`(handler).removeCallbacks(ArgumentMatchers.any(Runnable::class.java))
    }

    @Test
    fun `When do something then `() {
        assertThat(doSomething()).isTrue()
    }
```

## Real method:

```
fun doSomething(): Boolean {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    ...
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mocked handler instance isn't being used by the tested class. The tested class is creating its own handler which is an Android dependency, considering that, you should use Robolectric test runner or receive the Handler in the constructor to properly mock the instance. My suggestion is to use Robolectric.

Receive as a parameter:

```
    @Mock
    private lateinit var handler: Handler

    private lateinit var myClass: MyClass

    init {
        initMocks(this)
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        doNothing().`when`(handler)
            .removeCallbacks(ArgumentMatchers.any(Runnable::class.java))
        myClass = MyClass(handler)
    }
```

Use Robolectric, in this case, you don't need to care about the Handler:

```
 @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
 @Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
 class MyClassTest {
    private lateinit var myClass: MyClass

    init {
        initMocks(this)
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        myClass = MyClass()
    }
}
```

You also have to add the dependencies to your build.gradle to use Robolectric:

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
```